# What's the proper way to deal with dialogs/modals in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, ngrx

I am building an app with [Angular](https://angular.io/) and [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). Some operations in the app have to be performed within a modal/dialog. For this reason I use `MatDialog`.

For example, suppose I have to delete a `user` and this should happen within a dialog. The easiest implementation would look something like this:

**Solution 1**

```
deleteUser(user: User): void {
    const deleteUserDialogRef = this._dialog
        .open(DeleteUserDialogComponent, { data: { user } });

    deleteUserDialogRef
        .afterClosed()
        .subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
            if (confirmed) {
                this.usersService.delete(user.id);
            }
        });
}
```

**Solution 2**

Now, imagine that you'd like to have a loading spinner within the dialog that indicates that the operation is still pending. To keep the dialog simple, you would have to sacrifice the parent component that has actually opened it.

First, instead of actually closing the dialog upon user clicking the *Confirm* button, you would have to emit an event through an `EventEmitter`. Then, you'd have to listen to that event from the parent:

```
// ..
deleteUserDialogRef
    .componentInstance
    .confirmed
    .subscribe(() => this.usersService.delete(user.id))
```

And in order to change the `loading` input of the dialog, you'd have to do this:

```
this.usersService
    .deleteUserLoading$
    .subscribe(loading => {
        deleteUserDialogRef
            .componentInstance
            .data
            .loading = loading;
    });
```

This is not hard to implement, but imagine if you have to do the same for all of your CRUD operations. Your dialogs will be simple (and presentational), but your container component would become huge, and possibly, difficult to read and manage.

**Solution 3**

Instead of following *Solution 2*, you may try to make your dialogs smart. You may directly inject your services/store in the modal and take care of requests, loading states internally. The drawback, however, is that you'd have to inject your user data via a service/store selectors, because you should not use @Inputs() in a smart component.

Thus, you'd have to do something like this:

```
// Container
// ..
deleteUser(user: User): void {
    this.usersService.selectUser(user);

    const deleteUserDialogRef = this._dialog.open(DeleteUserDialogComponent);

    deleteUserDialogRef
        .afterClosed()
        .subscribe(() => this.usersService.deselectUser());
}

// Dialog
// ..
this.user$ = this.usersService.selectedUser$;
```

So, my question is what is the right way to design this - *Solution 2*, *Solution 3* or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution would be to do this with NgRx Effects.

Because it hides the form logic handling from the component, and the same dialog can be used from multiple components. The form itself stays "dumb" and the logic moves into the effect.

```
@Effect()
openDialog = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(LoginActionTypes.OpenLoginDialog),
  exhaustMap(_ => {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialog);
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }),
  map((result: any) => {
    if (result === undefined) {
      return new CloseDialog();
    }
    return new LoginDialogSuccess(result);
  }),
);
```

More info at [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#2-handling-the-flow-of-a-angular-material-dialog)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I can't relate it to the issue with the `loading` input. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: The dialog would dispatch a `DeleteUser` action, this action would set the status flag to loading, we have a selector based on this state property to show the loading spinner. The save action is also handled by another effect, if the save is successfull the save effect closes the the dialog with `this.dialog.closeAll()`.

Comment: So the dialog would have to inject the store as in **Solution 3**?

Comment: Indeed, dialog has the store injected and calls `store.dispatch(deleteUser(userId))`

Comment: Alright, so then in order to be able to visualize `user` data within the dialog itself, I would have to use a selector `this.user = this.store.pipe(select(selectedUser));`. In addition I would have to set this `selectedUser` property upon opening the modal and unset it upon closing. For example, `store.dispatch(openDeleteUserModal(user))` and in the reducer I set `selectedUser = payload`. Then in `closeDeleteUserModal` I set `selectedUser = null`. Is this what you were trying to say?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't needed to set the `selectedUser`. Nothing wrong with it, but it can also be passed as an input from the action to the dialog (inside the effect).

Comment: Yes, but if you pass it as an input, wouldn't that contradict with the idea of smart and dumb components. Meaning, dumb components have inputs and outputs. Smart ones have services/store, etc. If I have a component with both the store inject and an input, I think this is incorrect architecture. Do you agree?

Comment: Correct, sometimes I use an input tho - but this is when the form itself does not rely on selectors. Or if the data can't be changed from external sources (e.g. websockets).

Comment: I have a use case where I want to pass in also lets say a predefined set of events, and based on which event type led to confirmation dialog open and closed, i want to dispatch new actions, lets say, userDeleted, userCreated etc. The reason is that confirmation dialog is a generic component reused everywhere right now and i am moving it to ngrx ! Does this approach looks OK from good practice perspective ? Clearly I will have to also pass in i think some additional props/events names along to dispatch new actions